# vuejs3 beforeUnmount and unmounted not throwing alerts

Tags: vuejs3

learning vuejs3 and event hooks with this code

```
<template>
      <div>
        <h1>Vue Lifecycle hooks</h1>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(item, n) in list" :key="n">
            {{ item }}
            <button @click="deleteItem(item)">Delete</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        'Apex Legends',
        'A Plague Tale: Innocence',
        'ART SQOOL',
        'Baba Is You',
        'Devil May Cry 5',
        'The Division 2',
        'Hypnospace Outlaw',
        'Katana ZERO',
        'testing unmounted hooks',
      ],
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    alert('beforeCreate: data is static, thats it')
  },
  created() {
    alert('created: data and events ready, but no DOM')
  },
  beforeMount() {
    alert('beforeMount: $el not ready')
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    alert('beforeUnmount: about to blow up this component')
  },
  unmounted() {
    alert('unmounted: this component has been destroyed')
  },
}
</script>
```

every event hook throws an alert pop up except for the last two `beforeUnmount` and `unmounted`

I've googled it and haven't found anything explaining where the issue might be. The code has do it yourself write the code to learn and written code that you just need to install requirements and it should run, both don't show this so I'm thinking their either deprecated or namechanged with fail silently.

Comment: Well we know they're not deprecated because they exist in the [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#beforeunmount).  The issue is you've not provided enough details about how you're testing these hooks.  How is it that you're triggering your component to unmount?  if it's something like closing the tab/window, it will not trigger the hooks as it immediately destroys the entire app.  Something like toggling the component with `v-if` will call the unmount hooks.  See this [Vue Playground example](https://shorturl.at/HNO35) (use toggle btn and observe console logs)

Comment: I trigget unmount by clicking the delete that removes the button

Comment: These are **component** lifecycle hooks.  All of the code you've posted, both the template and script code together, makes up a [single component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html).  `<button>` is an HTML element and is a small part of your component.  Deleting it does not trigger the unmount hook.  Since removing a button causes the DOM to rerender, it would only trigger the [updated](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#updated) hook